# Override the output of display_errors

Tags: php, json

I’m creating a REST api which needs to only be able to output JSON data, however, during testing if there’s an error it doesn’t get reported because the data returns (as a string).

My format of the JSON output includes a section for errors, i.e {data: {error: {}}}, is it possible to override the output of errors so that I can format them in to my custom format?

Comment: A somewhat uncommon but feasible alternative for debugging and testing is to pass error messages per `header("X-Error: whatever")` alongside the paylod. Likewise use the error_handler approach for this, like hakre said.

Answer (score 1):

Sure it is. It's called [display_errors](http://php.net/display_errors) in PHP and it is a configuration setting.

This should have been disabled on your production server *anyway* already. So if it is still on, please disable it now. Also double check all your PHP configuration settings on the production server against the `php.ini-production` file that ships with your PHP.

You can then set your own error handler via [`set_error_handler`](http://php.net/set_error_handler) and collect all the errors and then add the one you're interested in to the JSON response.